# How can I force the session id in the Authentication object to be updated after a successful authentication when protecting against session fixation?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I need to record user login and logout events using the new session id generated after a successful authentication when protecting against session fixation.  I noticed the sessionId value in the Details object of the Authentication object does not get updated after the new session is created.  I've spent the last two days reading a lot of the javadoc and searching for answers on the web.  I found [this old post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/102024-incorrect-authentication-detail-sessionid-in-authenticationsuccessevent-event?p=551154#post551154) by Luke Taylor.  I tried his suggestion but it did not seem to work, so I tried creating a CustomWebAuthenticationDetails that allowed me to set the sessionId to the new value (I couldn't extend WebAuthenticationDetails because instance variable sessionId is final) and then using a CustomSessionAuthenticationStrategy that extended SessionFixationProtectionStrategy and overrode method onSessionChange. In this method, I updated the Details object in the Authentication object with an instance of CustomWebAuthenticationDetails that contained the new sessionId. This seemed to work, but once I logged out and logged back in, I got a java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails cannot be cast to org...CustomWebAuthenticationDetails.  I understood why I got the exception, so after searching some more, I tried creating a CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource and injecting it into an instance of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, but got an error saying "authenticationManager must be specified".  When I tried to also inject the AuthenticationManager, I realized I couldn't because I'm using a RemoteAuthenticationManager with my application.  At this point, I don't know what else to to try, so any suggestions will be much appreciated.

I would also like to know the reason why the sessionId is not updated in the Authentication object after a new session is created to protect against session fixation.  Would doing this make the application less secure?  If so, how?

Thanks,

Pat